# Preload at gdscript4

Tags: godot, preload

I write these codes at godot4:

var all_pieces = [
preload ("")
];

And source of image at "".

But I save main scene, this image doesn't show.

I don't know problem.

Comment: `preload` does not show an image. It loads it into memory. If you want to show an image, you can (1) assign it as the texture for a `Sprite` node, or (2) write a custom `_draw` function that displays the preloaded image.

Comment: Thanks.How to write the preload command in Godot 4 without errors?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

*It is a real shame that the term GDScript 4 is not correct. The language and the engine are versioned separately, and Godot 4 has GDScript 2.*

---

Using `preload` the way you are would work. Which is something like this:

```
var all_pieces := [ preload ("res://something.png") ]
```

*Here the `:` is telling Godot to infer the type (which in this case is an `Array`). I want to highlight that `preload` works with resource paths. And I removed the unnecessary `;`.*

---

> But I save main scene, this image doesn't show.

You are loading the resource, not showing it. I would need to know where and how you want to show it.

For example, if your script is attached to an `Sprite2D` you would be able to set its `texture` like this:

```
texture = all_pieces.pick_random()
```

Here `pick_random` will take an element from the `Array` randomly. *You need to have called `randomize()` beforehand (for example in `_ready`) otherwise the results will be the same each run.*

---

In comments, Silvio Mayolo mentions that you can use `_draw`. I'll expand on that.

All classes that extend `CanvasItem` have a virtual `_draw` method, which you would override:

```
func _draw() -> void:
    pass
```

There you can use the methods of `CanvasItem` for custom drawing. In this case, you could use `draw_texture` to render your texture:

```
func _draw() -> void:
    var piece_position := Vector2.ZERO
    draw_texture(all_pieces.pick_random(), piece_position)
```

*You could also use `draw_texture_rect` or `draw_texture_rect_region`.*

Be aware that you need to call `queue_redraw` to tell Godot it needs to call `_draw` again.

---

*Note that the above examples are for 2D.*